# Fourier Series estimation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I know that the Fourier coefficient of $t\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\vert t\vert}}$ are given by some Fresnel integral, and behave like $O(n^\frac{-1}{2})$. Reciprocally, if I get a Fourier Series whose coefficients are $c_n= \frac{\epsilon_n}{n^\frac{1}{2}}$ with $\epsilon_n\in\{-1,1\}$, does there is any chance that
$$\left\vert \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{in\pi t} \right\vert \leq \frac{C} {\sqrt{\vert t\vert}},$$ for some $C>0$ and $t\in[-1,1]\setminus{0}?
Thx

Comment: This is not very clear. Do you want to find a constant $C$ such that the partial sums of the Fourier series (over which interval?) of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}$ are bounded by $\frac{C}{\sqrt{|t|}}$?

Comment: I specified my guess, is it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
c_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\hphantom{-}|n|^{-1/2}&\text{if }n\equiv0,1\pmod{4}\\
-|n|^{-1/2}&\text{if }n\equiv2,3\pmod{4}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ne^{in\pi/2}
$$
diverges ($t=1/2$).